# How to create and update a text file in php so that the last sent message can be displayed

Tags: php, mysql, database, file

I am a Telecommunication Engineering student and I am not very good with coding using php and mysql. What I want is for my arduino to get data from the website haider.paks.pk/1/main.html The message is written by the user and then send it is pressed. upon sending the message a pop-up message is displayed. After that it goes to another page that only displays the last message send into it. I want this last message to be displayed in a text file that is created in php. How would I do it?

I want the webpage that will display the last sent message to act like this
http://projects.flowingdata.com/holidays/current-rates.txt

It should get updated as soon as the new data is sent into it. It must have this .txt format, that is necessary for me to access the data using arduino.

**Code for main page**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="get_msg.php" method="post">


<p>Enter your message:<br />
<textarea name="sms" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!" onclick="show()"></p>


</form>
<script>
function show() {
    alert("Message send successfully");
}
</script>
     <input type="button" name="b1" value="Show History" onclick="location.href='history.php'">
</body>
</html>
```

**Code for History Page**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> History  </h1>
    <?php

 require_once('db_con.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM message ";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $all = array();

 $id = array();
 $sms = array();
    ?>

    <?php

 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
     //echo $res['m_id'];

     echo $res['body_text']; ?>
    <br />
    </p>
    <?php

     array_push($id,array("Message ID: "=>$res['m_id']));
     array_push($sms,array("Text: "=>$res['body_text']));

 }

// echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Code for the webpage where the last message data is sent**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
      $num;
      require_once('db_con.php');
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM message ";
      $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>

<?php
  while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
      {
        $num++;
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM message where m_id=$num";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_object($result);
echo $row->body_text;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, add the relevant PHP code to the question instead of making an image. Secondly, do you have a column in your db that automatically updates a `datetime` column on insert?

Comment: There is an edit button in the answer and a delete button for comments..

Comment: @Xorifelse Am I doing anything wrong? Will you please guide me?

Comment: You should add the could to the question and not to the comment just click edit on your question and paste your code. Select it and then press the 2 brackets on top.

Comment: in file *get_msg.php* `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` Then you have the value you want to write into a file. However, instead of writing it into a file I would suggest another script outputting the contents directly from the database. Use the `header()` function in php to output a `text/plain` file. This way your "txt" file is always updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the following part of the code on the web page where the last message is sent

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $dept where m_id=$num";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_object($result);
//echo $row->body_text;
```

I added this part

```
$message = $row->body_text;
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt =$row->body_text;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
header("location:newfile.txt");
?>
```

**Note: 
"w+" (Read/Write. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)**

Answer (score 0):

Write your message in the php file as:

```
<?php
$message = $row->body_text;
$fp = fopen('file.php','w');
fwrite($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

or you can use

```
file_put_contents($filename, $content)
```

Comment: And this answers the question, how?

Comment: You have got your message body, now copy and paste the above code and replace 'file.php' with your filepath, Try it and let me know

Comment: I think @Haider wants to write every answer in the file. So, you need to give tha append flag?

Comment: @KoenHollander I don't want to write every answer to be displayed in the file. I only need the last answer to be displayed in it.

For example check this out http://projects.flowingdata.com/holidays/current-rates.txt

I exactly want my last message to be displayed like this in the tags so that I can access it through the arduino.

Comment: @KoenHollander I just want the data on the page http://haider.paks.pk/1/index2.php to be displayed like the one in the above link and in a text file

Comment: But what is the location or name of the file to which you want to write the data?

Comment: @Rahul The text file is not created yet, if you need screenshots of the database, then I can share it

Comment: @HaiderRehman , is "echo $row->body_text;" prints the message that you need to save in your file?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, this prints the message that I need and it is done using the counter in the while loop and it reaches the last value on the history page and then it displays it. I want the same procedure to happen in the text file.

Comment: Could you paste this code after echo $row->body_text and see what happens:
`$message = $row->body_text;
$fp = fopen('Path to your text file','w');
fwrite($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);`
then open that file and see if it contains the message

Comment: @Rahul Nothing happens. The data appears just like it was appearing before. No file is created.